# Does anyone know how to use UITableViewController to implement UISearchController in Xamarin.iOs without using StoryBoards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement **UISeachController** through a **UITableViewController** in Xamarin.iOs. I have created an XIB file in XCode and then have implemented the **UITableViewController** in the **.cs** file.

When I go back to the XCode designer view, I am unable to set the **File Owner View Outlet**, which causes the application to throw an exception which says -

*Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "SearchViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.*

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Set the referencing outlet of main view in your `SearchViewController`

[image]

Comment: This is working when using a `UIView`, but I am using a **UITableViewController**. I am unable to link the file owner to the same by dragging a Outlet.